# Grouping & aggregating on level 1 index & assigning different aggregation functions using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
                2019            2020            2021        2022
A       1       10              15              15          31
        2       5               4               7           9
        3       0.3             0.4             0.4         0.7
        4       500             600             70          90
B       1       10              15              15          31
        2       5               4               7           9
        3       0.3             0.4             0.4         0.7
        4       500             600             70          90
C       1       10              15              15          31
        2       5               4               7           9
        3       0.3             0.4             0.4         0.7
        4       500             600             70          90
D       1       10              15              15          31
        2       5               4               7           9
        3       0.3             0.4             0.4         0.7
        4       500             600             70          90
```

I am trying to group by the level 1 index, `1, 2, 3, 4` and assign different aggregation functions for those `1, 2, 3, 4` indexes so that `1` is aggregated by `sum`, `2` by `mean`, and so on. So that the end result would look like this:

```
            2019            2020            2021        2022
1           40              ...             ...         # sum
2           5               ...             ...         # mean
3           0.3             ...             ...         # mean
4           2000            ...             ...         # sum
```

I tried:

```
df.groupby(level = 1).agg({'1':'sum', '2':'mean', '3':'sum', '4':'mean'})
```

But I get that none of `1, 2, 3, 4` are in columns which they are not, so I am not sure how should I proceed with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with a custom function as follows:

```
import numpy as np

aggs = {1: np.sum, 2: np.mean, 3: np.mean, 4: np.sum}
def f(x):
    func = aggs.get(x.name, np.sum)
    return func(x)
     
df.groupby(level=1).apply(f)
```

The above code uses sum by default so `1` and `4` could be removed from `aggs` without any different results. In this way, only groups that should be handled differently from the rest need to be specified.

Result:

```
      2019    2020   2021    2022               
1     40.0    60.0   60.0   124.0
2      5.0     4.0    7.0     9.0
3      0.3     0.4    0.4     0.7
4   2000.0  2400.0  280.0   360.0
```

Comment: Interesting solution! I do wonder why you use the np.sum in the get of the dictionary.

Comment: @BorutFlis: It's not necessary if all index values are in the `aggs` dictionary but I thought it's better to have a default value. For example, if most groups should use e.g. sum then these do not need to be included in `aggs` (so in the above example 1 and 4 could be removed and only the specified ones will be handled differently). I added some more info regarding this in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you were after avoiding for loops. Slice and group by index and agg conditionally.

```
df1 = (
        df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(level=1)]).agg(
            lambda x: x.sum() if x.index.get_level_values(level=1).isin([1,4]).any() else x.mean())
        
         
      )
df1



    2019    2020   2021   2022
1    40.0    60.0   60.0  124.0
2     5.0     4.0    7.0    9.0
3     0.3     0.4    0.4    0.7
4  2000.0  2400.0  280.0  360.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the response on other question, this approach works. Is there a reason why I would not get the expected result using my way  on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70593603/grouping-aggregating-on-level-1-index-assigning-different-aggregation-functi)?

Comment: Not sure I understood you