# Grouping & aggregating on level 1 columns & assigning different aggregation functions using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a data frame

```
                             albumin bilirubin albumin bilirubin
                                mean      mean   count     count
id             class                                    
142345             a            3.4       1.0     1.0       1.0
                   a            3.2       2.0     0.0       0.0
                   b            3.1       1.0     0.0       0.0
                   b            2.7       0.0     3.0       0.0
```

I am trying to group over row `['id', 'class']` and affect a different aggregation functions to level 1 of my columns. I want to affect the `mean` to mean columns and `sum` to count columns, in order to obtain:

```
                             albumin bilirubin albumin bilirubin
                                mean      mean   count     count
id             class                                    
142345             a            3.3       1.5     1.0       1.0
                   b            2.9       0.5     3.0       0.0
```

I've found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70563360/grouping-aggregating-on-level-1-index-assigning-different-aggregation-functi). But I can't find a way to adapt it.

I've tried:

```py
def f(x):
    aggs = {"mean": np.mean, "count": np.sum}
    func = aggs.get(x.name, np.sum)
    return func(x)
     
grouped=df.groupby(['id', 'class'], axis=0, level=1 ).apply(f)
```

and I get the error

`TypeError: 'Categorical' object is not callable`

EDIT: suppose there are lots of columns in my df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, but not totally convinced about it.

```py
mean_grouped = df.groupby(['id', 'class']).mean().loc[:, idx[:, ['mean']]] 
sum_grouped = df.groupby(['id', 'class']).sum().loc[:, idx[:, ['count']]] 
df_out = pd.concat([mean_grouped, sum_grouped])
```